# How to login to WordPress Offline?

Tags: wordpress, offline

I have asked a question yesterday that how to install WordPress Offline. And I got the answer but I can't login to WordPress Offline. How to do that offline? If I need internet connection, I have my friends PC. So,if I log in there and took that on my computer via pen drive, will it work?

Comment: Is your wordpress website working locally ? If so, did you tried to go to `http://yousite.test/wp-admin/` page ? What is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install WordPress locally? You probably set a local URL (like http://localhost/wp-login.php) to access the site offline.

Comment: so did you remember the URL? You just need to add /wp-admin/ or /wp-login.php after the URL to access the WordPress backend in your browser.